# Classification when variables are observed as a group

Tags: classification, binary-data

How do I classify variables when the classifying binary output is known only for groups of variables?

Here is a concrete example: a person eats different types of foods on different days, and she either has an allergic reaction (to something she ate that day), or she does not. These data are available for a number of days. What foods is the person allergic to?

Here is a toy example:

```
Food    day1    day2    day3    day4    day5    day6    day7    day8    day9
avocado 1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
banana  0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
grapes  0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
tuna    1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
salmon  0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
sardines    1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
melon   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
yogurt  1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0

Reaction    1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1
```

(On day1, she ate avocado, tuna, sardines and yogurt, and had an allergic reaction; etc.)

With real data, you cannot do simple elimination (all foods she ate on days with no reaction are safe to eat), because there will be false positives and false negatives in the data. I tried this and ran into contradictions. A probabilistic approach is needed (result would be something like: 99% allergic to bananas, 10% allergic to melons, etc.).

This is not a regression problem, because we assume that there is no additive effect. The person has either eaten something she is allergic to or she has not - eating two foods she is allergic to have the same effect as eating one (Reaction=1).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something similar to MLE. Since the function here is not in a form you can take derivatives of, i.e. probability of reaction = max({b_i * X_i}), I would simulate over the space of beta of all food items (each between 0 and 1) and pick the combination that fits the data best.